# renderItems problems in react-native FlatList

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to deliver data from data.json to video.js

```
<Image source={{ uri: video.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url }} 
 style={{ height: 200 }} />
```

and i want to make this file renderd in flatlist

```
<FlatList 
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  data={data.items}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
  renderItem={(video) => <Video data={data.items}/>}
/>
```

when i try to render one item like data={data.items[0]} is shows up well, but it cant render some items the error says

- TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'video.snippet.thumbnails') *
  thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give me a snack url?

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@elencho/youtube

Comment: Change `renderItem={(video) => <Video data={data.items}/>` to `renderItem={(video) => <Video data={video.item}/>`

Comment: შენს სნექს დაქეშილი აქვს ერორი და შეგიძლია [აქ](https://snack.expo.io/o76I7zmUV) ნახო.

Answer (score 1):

This might help

```
// Change your `renderItem` like    
renderItem={({item}) => <Video data={item}/>}
```

Video.js

```
const { data } = this.props;

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={{ uri: data.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url }}
      style={{ height: 200 }}
    />
    ......
    <View style={styles.videoDetails}>
      <Text style={styles.videoTitle}>{data.snippet.title}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.videoStat}>
        {data.snippet.channelTitle} • {nFormatter(data.statistics.viewCount)} •{" "}
        {date(data.snippet.publishedAt)}
      </Text>
    </View>
    ......
  </View>
);
```

Comment: **renderItem** gives you **item**, **index**, and **separator**. So you can't access to **data.snippet** directly. I think there should be **data.item.snippet...**

Comment: @J.Doe `data` is just a prop I'm sending to `Video` component and extracted from props as shown above so data is actually contained single item from `items.data` array

Comment: You need smth like this **renderItem={({ item }) => <Video data={item}/>}**